# How to change content of drawer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a note taking app, where the idea is to have a drawer that you can open on click and add notes. I would like to implement a feature, where the user clicks on a note and the content of the drawer changes from a list of the notes to only the selected note, where you could edit the note and go back to the list of notes by clicking on a back arrow. I'm not sure how to approach the part where I could change the content of the drawer by clicking on a note. I would appreciate some suggestions!

Comment: Use React hooks? If the drawer is part of the layout, you can pass a NoteSelected state down to your individual note renderer.